# Fade in fade out in js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working in a cordova android app. Tried with bootstrap. failed. hence trying simple js
I have a function which returns text to html by

```
document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , It's Cool !!! "+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo2.svg\"/>";
```

when I trigger this button:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 65px;"> 
    <img src="img/temlogo.svg" width="50" height="50" onclick="foo(myCallback);"/>

</div>
```

If I want to fade out that text say after 1 min as a pop up by any pop up function (not with alert)
then what to do?

If bootstrap is possible : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers
let me know how, not working in my nexus. not getting the themeing and design at all and also in popover, in `data container` it holding only text, not executing any function

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create your own pop-over?
Just initialize or reset a timeout variable whenever the pop-over pops.

```
function foo(callback) {
    make_the_popover_show();
    popoverTimeout = setTimeout(clearPopover, 1000);
}

function clearPopover() {
    hide_the_popover();
}
```

Be sure to add identifiers to your pop-overs and to different timeouts, if you plan on showing multiple pop-overs at the same time.

Edit: I forgot to mention i wrote the variable as global. But you should write the code the way you like, [with or without global vars](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), and check out how to use [Timeouts](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) correctly.